# SQL in JdbcTemplate

Tags: sql, jdbctemplate

I've started to work with Spring JdbcTemplates and I have a question about SQL:

In the following code:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID = ?"; 
Customer customer = (Customer)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
            sql, new Object[] { custId }, new CustomerRowMapper());
```

What does "ID=?" means?
What are we looking for in this query?
The query seems to be unfinished.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is a replaceable SQL parameter.  The "new Object[] { custId }" parameter in the second statement supplies the value of the parameter.  E.g., if the value of "custId" were 42, then the resultant SQL query would be "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID = 42".  You should use parameterized SQL queries to reduce the possibility of SQL injection exploits and to facilitate caching of query plans.  I suggest reading up on them if you are not familiar.

Comment: Can I use JdbcTemplate to make named-parametered queries? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, take a look at the PreparedStatementCreator and PreparedStatementSetter classes.